# Swagger schema validation fails to read swagger spec from custom folder

Tags: java, api, swagger, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I am using attlasian library for schema validation of swagger.

> com.atlassian.oai.validator.restassured.OpenApiValidationFilter

```
private static final OpenApiValidationFilter SWAGGER_FILTER_ = new OpenApiValidationFilter( OpenApiInteractionValidator.createFor("swagger.yml") .withBasePathOverride("ApiBasePath") .build());
```

The above code works only when the swagger specs are available in src/main/api folder.

I am trying to read specs from `src/main/swagger` or `src/main/api/swaggers` folder.

> " java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find /api/swaggers/swagger.yml
> on the classpath"

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried including the folder path in the file name? See the examples in https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/52d64d800a716c235744a823af7dc80fa69ac817/swagger-request-validator-core/src/main/java/com/atlassian/oai/validator/OpenApiInteractionValidator.java#lines-67:71

Answer (score 0):

You can use real path, instead of Object

```java
OpenApiValidationFilter validationFilter = new OpenApiValidationFilter(
        OpenApiInteractionValidator.createFor(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src", "main", "swagger", "swagger.yml").toString()
        ).build());
```